# awk print Consecutive Number Range : Start and End Range

Tags: awk

Please help to print consecutive number ranges like [Start –End]  ..,

Sample Input

```
10
11
12
13
14
17
30
31
```

Desired output

```
10-14
17-17
30-31
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {a=$1;b=$1;next} ($1 != b+1){print a,"-",b; a=$1} {b=$1} END{print a,"-",b}' numbers
10 - 14
17 - 17
30 - 31
```

The above has two variables `a` and `b`.  `a` is the first number in the range.  `b` is the last number in the range that has been seen so far.

In `awk`, `NR` is the line (record) number.  The first part of the `awk` program just initializes the `a` and `b` variables with from the first line: `NR==1 {a=$1;b=$1;next}`

The next section of the program, `($1 != b+1){print a,"-",b; a=$1}`, checks to see if a new range has started.  If so the old range is printed and `a` is updated.

Regardless of whether a new range has started or not, `b` is updated to the value in the current line: `{b=$1}`.

After the last line has been seen, the `END` block is executed.  It just prints out the last range.

Comment: There's no need for the `b=$1` in two places. Also, the first block could just be `NR==1` (no need for the variable `f`). Otherwise, looks good :)